# MAAS PXE Boot problem

Tags: 14.04, boot, maas, pxe

I have an unordinary problem here,
1. I have my MAAS Server running on a hardware with ubuntu 14.04 server distro
2. pxe boot options are active in every other machines.
3. when trying to boot from the node machines I faced an error which is tring to find ubuntu 12.04 kernel and ofcorse it is not available becase I have added ubuntu 14.04 image in maas server .

[image]

I have not check ubuntu 12.04 in images but in pxe boot it tries to boot precise instead of trusty which is available in maas server

these are my log files:

```
==> /var/log/maas/pserv.log <==
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 2070): <RRQDatagram(filename=pxelinux.0, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 2070): <RRQDatagram(filename=pxelinux.0, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [ClusterClient,client] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 55059
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [ClusterClient,client] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 55059
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [ClusterClient,client] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca88c0>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [ClusterClient,client] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca88c0>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Got error: <tftp.datagram.ERRORDatagram object at 0x7fcb92c18e50>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Got error: <tftp.datagram.ERRORDatagram object at 0x7fcb92c18e50>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] (UDP Port 55059 Closed)
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] (UDP Port 55059 Closed)
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca88c0>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca88c0>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 2071): <RRQDatagram(filename=pxelinux.0, mode=octet, options={'blksize': '1456'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 2071): <RRQDatagram(filename=pxelinux.0, mode=octet, options={'blksize': '1456'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [ClusterClient,client] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 59084
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [ClusterClient,client] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 59084
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [ClusterClient,client] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca6128>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [ClusterClient,client] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca6128>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Final ACK received, transfer successful
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Final ACK received, transfer successful
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] (UDP Port 59084 Closed)
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] (UDP Port 59084 Closed)
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca6128>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca6128>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49152): <RRQDatagram(filename=pxelinux.cfg/37333336-3436-435a-3234-313130435359, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49152): <RRQDatagram(filename=pxelinux.cfg/37333336-3436-435a-3234-313130435359, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49153): <RRQDatagram(filename=pxelinux.cfg/01-2c-44-fd-96-2a-ac, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49153): <RRQDatagram(filename=pxelinux.cfg/01-2c-44-fd-96-2a-ac, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>

==> /var/log/maas/maas-django.log <==
ERROR 2014-02-06 19:59:11,536 maasserver Unable to identify boot image for (ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/commissioning): cluster 'maas' does not have matching boot image.

==> /var/log/maas/pserv.log <==
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [HTTPPageGetter,client] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 59043
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [HTTPPageGetter,client] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 59043
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [HTTPPageGetter,client] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca9758>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [HTTPPageGetter,client] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca9758>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Final ACK received, transfer successful
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Final ACK received, transfer successful
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] (UDP Port 59043 Closed)
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] (UDP Port 59043 Closed)
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca9758>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92ca9758>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49154): <RRQDatagram(filename=ifcpu64.c32, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49154): <RRQDatagram(filename=ifcpu64.c32, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 42954
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 42954
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92c6c5a8>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92c6c5a8>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Final ACK received, transfer successful
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Final ACK received, transfer successful
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49155): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49155): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] (UDP Port 42954 Closed)
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] (UDP Port 42954 Closed)
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92c6c5a8>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7fcb92c6c5a8>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49156): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel.cbt, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49156): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel.cbt, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49157): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel.0, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49157): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel.0, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49158): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel.com, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49158): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel.com, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49159): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel.c32, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
2014-02-06 19:59:11-0500 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('172.20.90.103', 49159): <RRQDatagram(filename=ubuntu/amd64/hwe-p/precise/no-such-image/boot-kernel.c32, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1408'})>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your node's hardware architecture is set to amd64/generic.

Comment: Thanks; this worked for me. Somehow after upgrading from MAAS 1.5, my node's architecture changed to `i386`, and I didn't have those images available.